# Como incluir arquivos de fonte (Glyphicons) do Bootstrap no Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-glyphicons

Nas minhas aplicações Rails eu costumo incluir o Bootstrap manualmente nas pastas:

- `app/assets/stylesheets/lib` (CSS) e
- `app/assets/javascripts/lib` (Javascript)

Tudo funciona perfeitamente com exceção dos **[Glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons)**.

Coloquei os arquivos de fontes na pasta `app/assets/fonts` porém ele não reconhece. O HTML `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>` gera o seguinte símbolo:

> [image: Glyphicon]

Abaixo o print do console do Firefox:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o trecho que contém as URLs (inalterado):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

não tem segredo é so colocar o css no local que desejar e as imagens em uma pasta.

verifique a configuraçaõ no css para ver se esta achando o caminho das imagens e pronto sem segredo.

Comment: Agora eu consegui: coloquei as fontes e apontei para a pasta `public` em vez da pasta `app/assets`.